# Spring boot test does not respect web security configuration

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-boot

I'm writing test for a Rest API controller. This endpoint is accessible without any authorization:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@Import(AppConfig.class)
class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired 
private UserDetailsRepository accountRepository;

@Autowired
private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

@Autowired
private JWTAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}

/*
 * Apparently, permitAll() doesn't work for custom filters, therefore we ignore the signup and login endpoints 
 * here
 */
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web)
        throws Exception {
    web.ignoring()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/signup");
}

/*
 * set user details services and password encoder
 */
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsServiceBean()).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

/* Stopping spring from adding filter by default */
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean rolesAuthenticationFilterRegistrationDisable(JWTAuthenticationFilter filter) {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
    registration.setEnabled(false);
    return registration;
}
```

}

The `JWTAuthenticationFilter` class:

```
@Component
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JWTAuthenticationFilter.class);
    private final static UrlPathHelper urlPathHelper = new UrlPathHelper();

    final static String defaultFilterProcessesUrl = "/**";

    public JWTAuthenticationFilter() {
        super(defaultFilterProcessesUrl);
        super.setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher(defaultFilterProcessesUrl)); //Authentication will only be initiated for the request url matching this pattern
        setAuthenticationManager(new NoOpAuthenticationManager());
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
        Authentication authentication = AuthenticationService.getAuthentication(request, customUserDetailsService);
        return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authentication);
    }

    @Override
    protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException failed) throws IOException, ServletException {
        logger.debug("failed authentication while attempting to access "+ urlPathHelper.getPathWithinApplication((HttpServletRequest) request));
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,"Authentication Failed");
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authResult);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        super.doFilter(req, res, chain);
    }
}
```

When I make a request (using postman) to 'signup' endpoint it works fine. But when I run the test, it hits `doFilter` and fails, as it doesn't get authenticated.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class AuthenticationControllerFTest {

    @Autowired 
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Test
    public void testCreate() throws Exception {
        Authentication authentication = Mockito.mock(Authentication.class);
        Mockito.when(authentication.getName()).thenReturn("DUMMY_USERNAME");
        Mockito.when(
                authenticationManager.authenticate(Mockito
                        .any(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class)))
                .thenReturn(authentication);

        String exampleUserInfo = "{\"name\":\"Test1234\",\"username\":\"test@test.com\",\"password\":\"Salam12345\"}";
        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .post("/signup")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(exampleUserInfo)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();

        MockHttpServletResponse response = result.getResponse();
        int status = response.getStatus();
        String content = response.getContentAsString();
        System.out.println(content);
        Assert.assertEquals("http response status is wrong", 200, status);
    }
}
```

Any idea on how to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The issue was resolved by adding the following code to the test class:

```
@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext context;

@Autowired
private Filter springSecurityFilterChain;

@Before
public void setup() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context)
            .addFilters(springSecurityFilterChain).build();
}
```

Comment: Here is a good read: https://spring.io/blog/2014/05/23/preview-spring-security-test-web-security

Comment: Thanks a lot, you've saved my day. I Really cannot understand why there is no clue for this in https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#test.

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

Comment: Look at the comment in the code: 
```/*
 * Apparently, permitAll() doesn't work for custom filters, therefore we ignore the signup and login endpoints 
 * here
 */```